# How to take output of a query function and provide it as input to second one in Humio

Tags: elasticsearch, command, pipe, kibana, humio

I'm trying to build a query in humio as below

regex(regex=".*MY NAME IS (?)", field=MESSAGE) | MESSAGE=${name}

Example of my server logs:

---

- MY NAME IS John
- John logged in on Monday
- MY NAME IS SID
- SID logged in on Tuesday
- SID logged out
- LOHI logged in on Wednesday
- LOHI logged out

---

**First part of the query is a regex function trying to retrieve all records that start with MY NAME IS from MESSAGE column and take the name and then I want to provide that name value to second statement to search the MESSAGE column data**

So per above server log example: I need a query that **can return below rows** in HUMIO:

---

- MY NAME IS John
- John logged in on Monday
- MY NAME IS SID
- SID logged in on Tuesday
- SID logged out

---

it **should not return below rows** as there is no MY NAME IS log statement

- LOHI logged in on Wednesday
- LOHI logged out

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're looking for something like this then:

```
regex("^MY NAME IS (?<userNameOfInterest>.*)", field=MESSAGE)
| join({ /* MESSAGE contains userNameOfInterest */ })
```

This takes a bit of work, since Humio can't check if a string contains a dynamic substring (at the moment). If the `MESSAGE` field has a limited number of permutations that you know up front, you can do something like this:

```
regex("^MY NAME IS (?<userNameOfInterest>.*)", field=MESSAGE)
| join({
    MESSAGE match {
      "* logged in on *" => regex("(?<userName>\S*) logged.*", field=MESSAGE);
      "* logged out" => regex("(?<userName>\S*) logged.*", field=MESSAGE);
      "MY NAME IS *" => regex("^MY NAME IS (?<userName>.*)$", field=MESSAGE); }
  }, field=userNameOfInterest, key=userName)
```

The `join` lets you combine two sets of data. In this case, the first `regex` finds all applicable user names, and the subquery extracts the user names from the other log events, so you can get the events that have a match.

If you go for this approach, you can also consider doing the `match` inside a parser, such that there is always a `userName` field ready to work with.

---

Alternatively, if you control the logs yourself, maybe you can tweak the messages by adding a user name field at the time they are sent?

- "MY NAME IS John. userName=John"
- "John logged in on Monday. userName=John"
- "MY NAME IS SID. userName=SID"
- "SID logged in on Tuesday. userName=SID"
- "SID logged out. userName=SID"
- "LOHI logged in on Wednesday. userName=LOHI"
- "LOHI logged out. userName=LOHI"

Then the query would be much more trivial to do, as the `join` subquery only needs to look for log events that contain any user name that it can join on:

```
regex("^MY NAME IS (?<userNameOfInterest>.*)", field=MESSAGE)
| join({ userName=* }, field=userNameOfInterest, key=userName)
```

I hope some of this is useful :)

Comment: @KasMS1990 - I updated the formatting of messages in the question, please can you recheck? Basically I need all logs that have the "name" value and the value name can be retrieved from text succeeding as "MY NAME IS ${name}"

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope you can use it :)